# how to use onclick event of <a>

Tags: asp.net

i want to use `onclick` event of `<a>` when i use srh like below doesn't work

```
...

<a oncick="reg_Click">...</a>
or
<a onclick="reg_Click" runat="server">...</a>

//function
  protected void reg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{...
```

Comment: oncick? shouldnt it be onclick?

Comment: it's my fault,i use `onclick` and doesn't work

Comment: okay... then can you also provide the function that you are calling and how you are calling it?

Answer (score 3):

if you use the anchor, you will call a javascript function.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function DoSomething() {
        alert('you clicked');
    }
</script>

<a onclick="DoSomething();" href="#">Test</a>
```

if you want to call some code-behind method, use LinkButton, instead

```
<asp:LinkButton Text="text" OnClick="MyServerSideMethod" runat="server" />
```

and in code behind

```
        protected void MyServerSideMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: i want to use `<a>` and go to another page and send query string,can i use(ovrride) `DoSomething` in code?

Comment: in this case you need to do the following <a href="/YourAnotherPage.aspx?MyParam=ValueOfYourParam">Go to another page passing param by query string</a>. Dont forget to mark it as answer

Comment: i need to gain ValueOfYourParam from code and send it

Comment: your question was about the use o click on a anchor element, if this question was answered, please mark it as answer. For other questions, please, create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that jumps out to me is that you should change 'oncick' to onclick

Comment: it's my fault,i use `onclick` and doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can call a JavaScript function only as it is a HTML tag only ,in that javascript you can call a server side function ,but not directly